# while deleting image from arraylist image get deleted but after added new image to arraylist previous image loaded

Tags: android, image-processing, arraylist, android-recyclerview

This is the class where image recycler view is set and images are added from folder in array list and it is loaded to image view..my problem is when image is deleted it gets deleted but after new image added previous image get loaded in image view please review my code and give me proper solution for it..

```
private ImageAdapterone imageAdapterone;
File file;

MenuItem item;
ArrayList<String> f;// list of file paths
File[] listFile;
RecyclerView recyclerImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    f = new ArrayList<String>();
    getFromSdcard();

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();

    System.out.println("memory is : " + maxMemory);


    recyclerImage = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage);


    imageAdapterone = new ImageAdapterone();
    int numberOfColumns = 2;

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    // GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    //gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerImage.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    recyclerImage.setAdapter(imageAdapterone);


    recyclerImage.addOnItemTouchListener(new
            RecyclerItemClickListener(CustomActivity.this, recyclerImage, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            item.setVisible(false);
            // correctmark.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (position == 0) {
                gotoNext(position, "rougescript_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                gotoNext(position, "tangerine_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                gotoNext(position, "gabriola", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                gotoNext(position, "tangerine_regular", R.color.colorBlack);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                gotoNext(position, "tangerine_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                gotoNext(position, "tangerine_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                gotoNext(position, "DancingScript-Regular", R.color.colorBlack);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                gotoNext(position, "jimnightshade_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                gotoNext(position, "gabriola", R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            }
            if (position == 9) {
                gotoNext(position, "rougescript_regular", R.color.colorBlack);
            }
            if (position == 10) {
                gotoNext(position, "rougescript_regular", R.color.colorBlack);
            }
            if (position == 11) {
                gotoNext(position, "jimnightshade_regular", R.color.colorWhite);
            }
            if (position == 12) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActivity.this, EditSettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            for (int i = 13; i < f.size(); i++) {
                goToNextActivity(position, "jimnightshade_regular", i, R.color.colorWhite);
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MyApplication.getPref().edit();
            editor.putInt("ImagePosition", position);
            editor.apply();

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //Toast.makeText(CustomActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("delete file position is on: " + position);


            for (int i = 13; i < f.size(); i++) {
                // for (int i = 13; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (position == i) {
                    item.setVisible(true);


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MyApplication.getPref().edit();
                    editor.putInt("DeletePosition", i);
                    editor.apply();


                    System.out.println("delete file position is on: " + MyApplication.getPref().getInt("DeletePosition", 0));

                }
            }
        }
    }));


}

private void goToNextActivity(int position, String font, int i, int color) {
    if (position == i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
        System.out.println("array position is : " + f.get(i));

        intent.putExtra("idone", f.get(i));
        intent.putExtra("font", font);
        intent.putExtra("CurrentFlag", "1");


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MyApplication.getPref().edit();
        editor.putString("ArrayPosition", f.get(i));
        editor.putInt("Color", color);
        editor.apply();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public void getFromSdcard() {

    file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Wallpaper Pack");
    System.out.println("folder is sdcard : " + file);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();
        System.out.println("list of file is: " + listFile.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            f.add((listFile[i].getAbsolutePath()));


            System.out.println("path is : " + listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

        }
    }
}

public void gotoNext(int id, String font, int color) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActivity.this, FullImageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("font", font);
    intent.putExtra("fonttag", "1");
    intent.putExtra("CurrentFlag", "0");
    intent.putExtra("color", color);


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MyApplication.getPref().edit();
    editor.putString("NewFont", font);
    editor.putInt("Color", color);
    editor.apply();

    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Glide.get(this).clearMemory();
}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_delete: 

   File(listFile[MyApplication.getPref().getInt("DeletePosition",0)].
   getAbsolutePath());
  +listFile[MyApplication.getPref().getInt("DeletePosition",0)]
  .getAbsolutePath());

   imageAdapterone.notifyItemRemoved(MyApplication.getPref()
  .getInt("DeletePosition",0));

            File file = new 
   File(listFile[MyApplication.getPref().getInt("DeletePosition", 
   0)].getAbsolutePath());


            file.delete();
            imageAdapterone.deleteItem(MyApplication.getPref()
         .getInt("DeletePosition", 0));
            imageAdapterone.notifyDataSetChanged();
            item.setVisible(false);


            break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Now this is the code for adapter where image arraylist is set using an glide..

```
         public class ImageAdapterone extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapterone.SingleTestRowHolder> {

    Context context;
    Bitmap myBitmap;

    @Override
    public SingleTestRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
        SingleTestRowHolder mh = new SingleTestRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageAdapterone.SingleTestRowHolder holder, int position) {

        byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(f.get(position), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

        if (position > 12) {
            holder.customText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.customText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        System.out.println("IMAGE POSITION: " + f.get(position));

        Glide.with(holder.thumbImage.getContext())
                .load(f.get(position))
                .override(300, 300)
                .centerCrop()

        StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))


                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(holder.thumbImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        System.out.println("INDEX OF DELETED ITEM: " + index);
        f.remove(index);

        notifyItemRemoved(index);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(index, f.size());

        System.out.println("IMAGES SIZE: " + f.size());

    }


    public class SingleTestRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbImage;
        TextView customText;

        public SingleTestRowHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            customText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customText);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's delete from arraylist not from device so every time it's get from device..as your code.

Comment: no its delete from device also here is the code below..                                                  
             File file = new 
            File(listFile[MyApplication.getPref().getInt("DeletePosition", 
             0)].getAbsolutePath());

            file.delete();